# VBA Download CSV from Website

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with a VBA script which I have written. It is being called 4 times to download 4 different csv files from a Website. If I execute the script step by step by pressing F8 it works fine. However, when I am running the whole script it doesn't download all files. Sometimes it downloads one or two files and sometimes None- it's kind of unpredictable!? Has anybody an idea what wrong with the code of the Sub DownloadIshares()?

Many thanks in advance

```
Sub Test()
DownloadIshares "EUN5"
DownloadIshares "IBCS"
DownloadIshares "LQDH"
DownloadIshares "SDIG"
End Sub

Sub DownloadIshares(inETFName As String)

Dim o_IE As InternetExplorer
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim o_TextStream As TextStream
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim urlETF As String
Dim links As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim link As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim WB_tmp As Workbook
Dim MainPath As String, MainUrl_1 As String, MainUrl_2 As String, UrlETF_No As String
Dim SearchForLink As String

MainPath = "U:\Entwicklung\Instrumentenabgleich_ETF\"
MainUrl_1 = "https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/site-entry?siteEntryAction=ACCEPT&targetUrl" _
    & "=%2Fde%2Fprofessionelle-anleger%2Fde%2Fprodukte%2F"
MainUrl_2 = "%2F%3FsiteEntryPassthrough%3Dtrue%26refer" _
    & "rer%3DtickerSearch%26locale%3Dde_DE%26userType%3Dinstitutional"

Select Case inETFName
    Case "EUN5"
        UrlETF_No = "251726"
        SearchForLink = "_Datenblatt_GroMiKV_IE00BF11F565.csv"
    Case "LQDH"
        UrlETF_No = "257320"
        SearchForLink = "_Datenblatt_GroMiKV_IE00BCLWRB83.csv"
    Case "IBCS"
        UrlETF_No = "251565"
        SearchForLink = "_Datenblatt_GroMiKV_IE0032523478.csv"
    Case "SDIG"
        UrlETF_No = "258126"
        SearchForLink = "_Datenblatt_GroMiKV_IE00BYXYYP94.csv"
End Select

urlETF = MainUrl_1 & UrlETF_No & MainUrl_2
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set o_IE = New InternetExplorer
o_IE.Visible = True
'o_IE.Visible = False

o_IE.Navigate urlETF
Do While o_IE.Busy Or o_IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = o_IE.Document
Set links = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each link In links
    'If InStr(link.href, "_Datenblatt_GroMiKV_IE00BCLWRB83.csv") Then
    If InStr(link.href, SearchForLink) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Text: " & link.innerText & vbCr & "URL: " & link.href
        'Set o_TextStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(link.href)
        Set WB_tmp = Workbooks.Open(link.href)
        WB_tmp.SaveAs MainPath & inETFName, xlCSV
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        WB_tmp.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens?  Do you get an error?  Does it timeout?

Comment: It just runs without producing the files and fires no error.

Comment: But sometimes it causes an Error: "Automation Error: Old Format or Invalid Type Library"

Comment: You've got a debug line.  Does that print anything when it doesn't download the file?

Comment: No, if it doesn't download anything it prints nothing. If I execute the script multiple times with F5 then it fires the above mentioned Automation Error.

Comment: So that means one of two things: 1) it's not hitting that line, or 2) the link might be null, which kills the entire line.  You could try using Nz to isolate which one it is.

Comment: hmm,but when I go throuh the script with F8 it hits every line. So the links do exist.

Comment: Sometimes, debugging introduces changes that don't mimic production.  It could be a load time issue; your best bet is to make that Debug line work, and put one right before the If line, as well.  That'll let you know what it's hitting.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow, may be I will find something. Thanks for your quick replies fbueckert.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code a lot!

```
Sub OpenCSV()
strURL = "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"
Application.Workbooks.Open (strURL)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your remark ryguy72. Unfortunately, the url changes daily so I think I have to navigate through the website to find the correct link among all existing links.

Comment: Is the target file based on a date, or is there some kind of data pattern that you can exploit?  There must be something that indicates where you need to go.  Pass that into the strURL as a parameter and concatenate it inyou your string using the '&' character.

Comment: yes it depends on the date but there is no regular pattern on how the date changes.